# Can't remove padding from body (ios) - Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

I can't get rid of the padding for my `body` element. I have tried setting `padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px` on the `body` element, but it does nothing. I have also tried setting `padding-top` and `padding-left` to `0`, but it did nothing.

I have made sure that the `#container` inside `body` does not have a margin, I tried setting it with `margin: 0` and `margin-left` `margin-right` set to `0`.

[image]

The `blue` area is `body`, the white area is the `#container`. I am trying to stretch the container to cover the whole body (get rid of the blue).

**relevant css**:

```
html {
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**js that creates the container**:

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.style.flex = "1 0 100%";
container.style.backgroundColor = "white";
container.style.display = "flex";
container.style.flexDirection = "column";
container.id = "container";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a container called `.app` just inside the `body` element, and I set its css to:

```
.app {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: -8px -8px 0px -8px;
}
```

The key part being:

```
margin: -8px -8px 0px -8px;
```

**Note**: I thought the `margin` was `10px` when I was looking at it, but it is actually `8px`.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important at end of every property. It is forced to ignore default browser CSS and apply your CSS.

```
html 
{
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Some developer is also using this to reset browser CSS.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

But, my suggestion is First use !important option, then reset all browser CSS, because, It also disturbs your other content of the webpage.